# adding text values into a circle in html page using JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an HTML page on which I am trying to display a sky plot. For the display, I am using the `D3` library in `JS`. 
Here is my code:

```
var deg2rad = Math.PI/180;
var width = 400, height = 350, radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 30;

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var r = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([90, 0])
            .range([0, radius]);

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
            .radius(function(d) {return r(d[1]);})
            .angle(function(d) {return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2;});

var gr = null;

createSkyplot();

function createSkyplot(){         
    gr = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "r axis")
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(r.ticks(5))
                .enter().append("g");

    gr.append("circle").attr("r", r).style('fill', 'white');

    gr.append("text")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return -r(d) - 4; })
        .attr("transform", "rotate(20)")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style('fill', 'blue')
        .text(function(d) { return d;});

    var ga = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "a axis")
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(d3.range(0, 360, 45))
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {return "rotate(" + (d - 90) + ")";});

    ga.append("line").attr("x2", radius).style('stroke', 'black').style('stroke-dasharray', '1,8');

    ga.append("text")
        .attr("x", radius + 6)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d < 360 && d > 90 ? "end" : null; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return d < 360 && d > 90 ? "rotate(180 " + (radius + 3) + ",0)" : null; })
        .text(function(d) { return d + "°"; });
}

function updateSkyPlot(d){
    var pos = [];
    var inview = d.inView;

    for (var elem in inview){
        if (inview.hasOwnProperty(elem)) {
            console.log(inview[elem].data[0]);
            // the azimuth should be in radians and substracted from (Math.PI/2)
            var d = [(Math.PI/2) - inview[elem].data[2]*deg2rad, inview[elem].data[1]]; 
            pos.push(d);
        }
    }

    var r = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([90, 0])
        .range([0, radius]);

    var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
        .radius(function(d) {return r(d[1]);})
        .angle(function(d) {return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2;});

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    svg.selectAll('circle').remove();

    gr.append("circle").attr("r", r).style('fill', 'white');

    svg.selectAll("point").data(pos).enter().append("circle").attr("class", "point")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                var coors = line([d]).slice(1).slice(0, -1);
                return "translate(" + coors + ")"})
        .attr("r", 8)
        .attr("fill",function(d,i){return color(i);});

}
```

I use the `updateSkyPlot(d)` method to update the plot. The input for this method is a `JSON` object of the next type:
`{"type" : "data", "inView" : {[prn, elv, azi], [prn, elv, azi] ..}}`.

When I run this code in the HTML page I am able to produce the next plot:
[image]

My question is, what would be the best way to add the prn number inside the corresponding circles?
What should I add to the code to make it work?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is Full HTML snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body style='background-color:lightgray'>
  <div id="chart" style='width: 400px; height: 400px; padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'></div>

  <script>
   var deg2rad = Math.PI/180;
            var width = 400, height = 350, radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 30;

            var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
      
            var r = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([90, 0])
       .range([0, radius]);
  
           var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
       .radius(function(d) {return r(d[1]);})
       .angle(function(d) {return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2;});

            var gr = null;

            createSkyplot();

   var json = {"type" : "GSV",
                        "inView" : [{"data" : [1, 45, 90]},
                                    {"data" : [3, 70, 225]}]
                       };
                       
            updateSkyPlot(json);

            function createSkyplot(){ 
             //////////////////////     
             gr = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "r axis")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(r.ticks(5))
        .enter().append("g");

                gr.append("circle").attr("r", r).style('fill', 'white');

             gr.append("text")
              .attr("y", function(d) { return -r(d) - 4; })
              .attr("transform", "rotate(20)")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .style('fill', 'blue')
                 .text(function(d) { return d;});
             /////////////////////

             /////////////////////
             var ga = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "a axis")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(d3.range(0, 360, 45))
        .enter().append("g")
             .attr("transform", function(d) {return "rotate(" + (d - 90) + ")";});

                ga.append("line").attr("x2", radius).style('stroke', 'black').style('stroke-dasharray', '1,8');
   
             ga.append("text")
                 .attr("x", radius + 6)
                 .attr("dy", ".35em")
                 .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d < 360 && d > 90 ? "end" : null; })
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return d < 360 && d > 90 ? "rotate(180 " + (radius + 3) + ",0)" : null; })
                 .text(function(d) { return d + "°"; });
             /////////////////////
            }

function updateSkyPlot(d){
 var pos = [];
 var inview = d.inView;

 for (var elem in inview){
  if (inview.hasOwnProperty(elem)) {
   // the azimuth should be in radians and substracted from (Math.PI/2)
   var d = [(Math.PI/2) - inview[elem].data[2]*deg2rad, inview[elem].data[1]]; 
   pos.push(d);
  }
 }

 var r = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([90, 0])
  .range([0, radius]);

 var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
  .radius(function(d) {return r(d[1]);})
  .angle(function(d) {return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2;});

 var color = d3.scale.category20();

 svg.selectAll('circle').remove();

 gr.append("circle").attr("r", r).style('fill', 'white');

    svg.selectAll("point").data(pos).enter().append("circle").attr("class", "point")
       .attr("transform", function(d) {
          var coors = line([d]).slice(1).slice(0, -1);
          return "translate(" + coors + ")"})
       .attr("r", 8)
  .attr("fill",function(d,i){return color(i);});
  
}

  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: More complete than this? What else do you need?

Comment: I have added the full HTML snippet. The input for the socket is a JSON string as explained at the top.

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 26
}

Comment: Fixed that issue. Changed the snippet. When running the snippet it says that d3 is not recognized, however, on the computer it runs perfectly. Can we please get back to the original question ...

Comment: the snippet could be run at [link] (http://cssdeck.com/labs) just checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possiblity:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body style='background-color:lightgray'>
  <div id="chart" style='width: 400px; height: 400px; padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'></div>

  <script>
   var deg2rad = Math.PI/180;
            var width = 400, height = 350, radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 30;

            var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
      
            var r = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([90, 0])
       .range([0, radius]);
  
           var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
       .radius(function(d) {return r(d[1]);})
       .angle(function(d) {return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2;});

            var gr = null;

            createSkyplot();

   var json = {"type" : "GSV",
                        "inView" : [{"data" : [1, 45, 90]},
                                    {"data" : [3, 70, 225]}]
                       };
                       
            updateSkyPlot(json);

            function createSkyplot(){ 
             //////////////////////     
             gr = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "r axis")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(r.ticks(5))
        .enter().append("g");

                gr.append("circle").attr("r", r).style('fill', 'white');

             gr.append("text")
              .attr("y", function(d) { return -r(d) - 4; })
              .attr("transform", "rotate(20)")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .style('fill', 'blue')
                 .text(function(d) { return d;});
             /////////////////////

             /////////////////////
             var ga = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "a axis")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(d3.range(0, 360, 45))
        .enter().append("g")
             .attr("transform", function(d) {return "rotate(" + (d - 90) + ")";});

                ga.append("line").attr("x2", radius).style('stroke', 'black').style('stroke-dasharray', '1,8');
   
             ga.append("text")
                 .attr("x", radius + 6)
                 .attr("dy", ".35em")
                 .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d < 360 && d > 90 ? "end" : null; })
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return d < 360 && d > 90 ? "rotate(180 " + (radius + 3) + ",0)" : null; })
                 .text(function(d) { return d + "°"; });
             /////////////////////
            }

function updateSkyPlot(d){
 var pos = [];
 var inview = d.inView;

 for (var elem in inview){
  if (inview.hasOwnProperty(elem)) {
   // the azimuth should be in radians and substracted from (Math.PI/2)
   var d = [(Math.PI/2) - inview[elem].data[2]*deg2rad, inview[elem].data[1]]; 
   pos.push({ "angle": d, "label": inview[elem].data[0] });
  }
 }

 var r = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([90, 0])
  .range([0, radius]);

 var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
  .radius(function(d) {return r(d[1]);})
  .angle(function(d) {return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2;});

 var color = d3.scale.category20();

 svg.selectAll('circle').remove();

 gr.append("circle").attr("r", r).style('fill', 'white');

    var points = svg.selectAll("point")
     .data(pos)
     .enter()
     .append("a")
     .attr("transform", function(d) {
      var coors = line([d.angle]).slice(1).slice(0, -1);
      return "translate(" + coors + ")"
     });

    points.append("circle")
     .attr("class", "point")
       .attr("r", 8)
  .attr("fill",function(d,i){return color(i);});

 points.append("text")
  .text( function(d) { return d.label })
  .attr("transform", "translate(-4,5)")
  
}

  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

---

I have kept the label in data (when you create the `pos` array with circle positions):

```
var pos = [];

for (var elem in inview) {
    if (inview.hasOwnProperty(elem)) {
        var d = [(Math.PI/2) - inview[elem].data[2]*deg2rad, inview[elem].data[1]]; 
        // This is the modified line:
        pos.push({ "position": d, "label": inview[elem].data[0] });
        // pos.push(d);
    }
}
```

Then instead of directly creating the circles, I create an intermediate container which will contain for each data point both the circle and the text label; and which is translated to its position:

```
var points = svg.selectAll("point")
    .data(pos)
    .enter()
    .append("a") // The container
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var coors = line([d.position]).slice(1).slice(0, -1);
        return "translate(" + coors + ")"
    });
```

This way we can include for each data point both the circle:

```
points.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("fill",function(d,i){return color(i);});
```

and the label:

```
points.append("text")
    .text( function(d) { return d.label })
    .attr("transform", "translate(-4,5)")
```